# Compare 2 columns in different workbooks and retrieve cell value from a third column

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 workbooks in Excel 2010 book1.xls and book2.xls, Example book1:

```
A            B         C       D         E
880006729    5016211   John    $0.000
```

From this workbook i only need Column B which is the Employee number and Column E which will be the place where i get the data from the other workbook

Example book2:

```
A            B         C
5016211      Canada    Sales
```

In this book I have these main columns but I only need column A and C. Both workbooks have more than 1000 rows im just showing and example of the data.

My goal is to search the value from book1 Column B (Employee Number) in book2, after it finds that specific number get the value in column C and paste it in Column E book1, In few words, I want to know which Business Unit each employee belongs to.

NOTE: book1 table can contain more than 1 row with same employee number, of course if this happens just repeat the word "Sales" using as reference the tables above.

the final table would look like this...

```
A            B         C       D         E
880006729    5016211   John    $0.000    Sales
```

Comment: You should look inot the [VLOOKUP FUNCTION](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-function-HP010343011.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

IN COLUMN E of book1.xls enter this formula and drag it down:

```
=VLOOKUP(B1,[Book2.xls]Sheet1!A1:C1000,3)
```

Change the `A1:C1000` to the range that has all the values in book2

Comment: I does work but keeps repeating Sales for all rows, im new to excel sorry

Comment: @user3271671 Are you copy pasting this down the column E? Or dragging it down?

Comment: Dragging it down, but nevermind i found the way, i clicked on Calculate now after dragging it down and it updated with the correct data, thanks a lot!!!